# Angular2 Call Function When the Input Changes

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

Child component:

```
export class Child {
    @Input() public value: string;
    public childFunction(){...}
}
```

Parent component:

```
export class Parent {
    public value2: string;
    function1(){ value2 = "a" }
    function2(){ value2 = "b" }
}
```

Parent view:

```
<child [value]="value2">
```

Is there any way to call childFunction() every time the value2 is changed in this structure?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use the `ngOnChanges()` [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges)

```
export class Child {
    @Input() public value: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
      this.childFunction()
    }
    public childFunction(){...}
}
```

or use a setter

```
export class Child {
    @Input() 
    public set value(val: string) {
      this._value = val;
      this.childFunction();
    }
    public childFunction(){...}
}
```

Comment: In the first method, can we determine which variable is changed?

Comment: The `changes` parameter contains an entry for each changed input. See the "lifecycle hook" link above for more details.

Comment: I noticed ngOnChanges() only gets called in the child component whenever the parent input property gets re-assigned. If any other operation happens, like if the parent input property is an array and new values are pushed to them, the child doesn't get updated. Correct?

Comment: @Aiguo That's correct. `ngOnChanges()` is only called after Angulars change detection detects a change and updates an `@Input()` binding.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is it possible if I assign same value than also it should be called? ex: this.value = true; if I again assign true than also I want to called. How it's possible?

Comment: @DarshanVachhani if you use the setter version, this is the default behavior

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes I used setter only but if value changes than only set method called.
I can't find issue.

Comment: @DarshanVachhani what else do you want to be called?

Comment: @Aiguo if its not wotk in array try  to clone the array and push to the new cloned array the new property -  if you want angular detect the change .

Comment: There's a lot of useful information in the comments here, it'd be really nice to get some of this information into the answer itself