# Angular: How to call function after the component got the Input data

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

I have a parent and child component. In the parent I am searching for a user and give the userId via @Input to my child component. This is working.

After my child component is getting the value I want to call a function so that I am getting the card from the user back. How do I do this? I always getting a card is undefined error.

```
<p (show)="serachForCard()">
  User: {{userId}}
  Card: {{card.id}}
</p>
```

My Idea was to call a function but it is still not working.

Function in my ts file:

```
serachForCard() {
        this.cardService.getCardByUserId(this.userId)
            .subscribe(
                (data: Card) => this.card= data
            )
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Call Function When the Input Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331125/angular2-call-function-when-the-input-changes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Implement `OnChanges` interface inside your child component and call your function from `ngOnChanges` method.

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() someInput: string;

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        // do something with this.someInput
    }
}
```

[Documentation: OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

> A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. Define an ngOnChanges() method to handle the changes.